# Dynamic filtering of api requests data - Javascript React. What is the best way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### Newbie question here.
There is data fetched from API (Django) and on the frontend (React) the user selects what he wants to have displayed. I'm struggling with passing the chosen data to filter/mapping - if i pass it as a variable then it is simply displayed literally

somecode ................
(data fetched)

let comparison = this.state.to   /*(this is what user choses to have displayed via form)

let output =`item.${ comparison }`; /* this transforms it into the text I would like to pass into the mapping function) */

{items.filter(item => this.state.from === item.country)
.map(item => (

- {item.country}
- {item.country2}
- {output}

))}

*/ and here I would like to first filter the data based on the user choice (this.state.from) and then display the data chosen by user (output). Ouput displays the string literally but i would like it to actually map the data corresponding to the choice.

so it will display

- Data
- Data
- item.(userchoice) (coming from {output})

Sorry if it is chaotic or obvious... :(

Comment: I didn't get everything, but i believe you're looking for `item[comparison]`.

Comment: Im not sure if this is the answer here - would you explain why?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't quite get your question neither, but what I understood is that you're trying to display a subset of an object base on some user input.
`const fruitsColors = {
  apple: "red",
  banana: "yellow",
}`
`const userChoice = "apple";`
`<div>{fruitsColors[userChoice]}</div>`
will display red; Is that what you wanted to achieve ? Or did I completely misunderstood

Comment: The user input is supposed to filter what data pulled from API is getting displayed. I'm looking for an efficient way to achieve that.